# Is it still possible to receive an SMS message from a specific sender without broadcasting it further to the default messaging app?

Tags: android

I am interested in receiving all SMS messages from a specific, known number from inside my application without broadcasting them further to the default messaging app and certainly, without getting a notification for them. I do not want to make my application the default messaging app as it is only supposed to receive data from another device through SMS. Is this still possible? I am asking as evidence seems to point out it is no longer doable.

I have tried and, as of right now, my application does receive all the SMS messages from the sender I specified and none other before any other app, thanks to the receiver priority declaration, but `broadcastReceiver.abortBroadcast()` no longer seems to work and neither does `broadcastReceiver.setResultCode(Intents.RESULT_SMS_HANDLED)`. If a full solution under the conditions described can no longer be implemented, I would be satisfied with only a way to turn off sound alerts and notifications for these messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this still possible?

That has not been possible since Android 4.4, which came out years ago.

> If a full solution under the conditions described can no longer be implemented, I would be satisfied with only a way to turn off sound alerts and notifications for these messages.

Write your own full SMS client, and offer this feature among others.

Or, find an existing open source full SMS client, and contribute this feature to that project.